# Argument passing in a bash script

Tags: bash, arguments, shift

I've got following bash script to do something for each parameter of the script

```
#! /bin/sh

while (($#)); do
 echo $1
 shift
done
```

But somehow, if I start it with the command `sudo ./test.sh foo1 foo2` it wont work. And the real strange thing is, that if I enter `sudo bash test.sh foo1 foo2` it works. Does anybody know what causes this strange behaviour?

Comment: What are the permissions on your script? What _doesn't work_ about the first attempt?

Comment: If you are writing a bash script put `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning. If you are writing sh script, don't use any of bash extensions.

Comment: please edit your question to include current output, expected output and any error messages (complete text). Impossible to debug given your descriptions. Good luck.

Comment: './test heh eheh' gives me
'./test: 6: 2: not found' sudo is not relevant, but using bash fixes it.

Comment: "it won't work" provides no information. Please post error messages or descriptions of unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified /bin/sh as your interpreter, which may not be bash. Even if it is bash, bash runs in POSIX mode when called as /bin/sh.

The `(( ))` command is a bash-specific feature. The following will work in any POSIX compliant shell:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
   echo $1
   shift
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried #!/bin/bash rather than sh?

Here's a link explaining the difference:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/difference-between-bin-bash-and-bin-sh-693231/

Answer (score 1):

This will work in either `sh` or `bash`:

```
for arg
do
    echo "$arg"
done
```

and it does the same thing as your script is intended to do without destroying the argument list.